# Time off request or time-off request?

Tags: hyphenation, time, compounds

Hello fellow grammar lovers!

I need some help.

I'm working on HR resources and have run into a bit of a conundrum about how to write about PTO.

I know that I "would like to take time off." But how do I go about "initializing a time-off request?"

My question: Is it appropriate to hyphenate *time off* when used as an adjectival noun to modify *request*?

My first thought is to use the hyphenated version to describe the noun (*request*), as nouns used to modify other nouns become adjectival nouns/noun modifiers/attributive nouns.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

J

Comment: Hello and welcome to the ELU. It is precisely _opinions_ that are off topic on this site. Have a look at the [helpcentre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) and maybe edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, but I wasn't implying that all grammar is opinion. (Grammar is most certainly *not* opinion). I was stating that what I found so far on the Internet was opinion (regarding my posted question). I have rephrased my question. Perhaps you would care to lend an answer?

Comment: [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/390825/hyphenation-in-compound-adjectives-like-in-demand-skills-on-call-service) discusses noun+preposition compounds like "in demand"/"in-demand" but the answer should explain your case, particularly Garner's quote.

Comment: Thank you. So, after reading the linked question, yes, the hyphen is appropriate and correct.

Comment: As far as I know, initialisation has nothing to do with grammar, *proprement dit*.  Initialisation has two purposes (apart from confusing old codgers like me): brevity and making up spreadsheet headings.  A possible second is that acronyms should be long enough to be distinctive and short enough to be memorable.  A key third is to avoid accidentally winding up with a word that sounds funny or rude.  I have not come across hyphens in acronyms.